# Adding an ActionListener to a custom component

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a custom component (which `extends JPanel`).

It looks something like this:

[image: Custom Component]

My question is: When I use it in another `JFrame`, how do i add an `ActionListener` to it, so that when I click any of the button it'll execute code in the `actionPerformed`?

I tried adding a `MouseListener` to it, but it didn't work.

EDIT: I'm sorry I'm not very clear on the component:
It consist of two `JButtons` (the "-" and "+") and a `JTextField`.
When the user clicks on either of them, the number in the middle increases or decreases.
All these 3 components are placed inside a `JPanel`.

EDIT 2: Here is the source code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ZoomSelector extends JPanel {
    protected JButton btnDecrement;
    protected JTextField txtNumber;
    protected JButton btnIncrement;

    private String currentValue, previousValue;

    public ZoomSelector() {
        setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, null, null));
        initGUI();

        txtNumber.setText("12");
        currentValue = "12";

        setSize(new Dimension(125, 26));
        validate();
    }

    public boolean hasChanged() {
        if(currentValue.equals(previousValue)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String getText() {
        return txtNumber.getText();
    }

    public void reset() {
        previousValue = txtNumber.getText();
        txtNumber.setText("12");
        currentValue = "12";
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean e) {
        btnDecrement.setEnabled(e);
        txtNumber.setEnabled(e);
        btnIncrement.setEnabled(e);
    }

    public void increment() {
        previousValue = txtNumber.getText();
        int number = Integer.parseInt(txtNumber.getText());
        if(number < 20) {
            number++;
            txtNumber.setText("" + number);
            currentValue = "" + number;
        }       
    }

    public void decrement() {
        previousValue = txtNumber.getText();
        int number = Integer.parseInt(txtNumber.getText());
        if(number > 0) {
            number--;
            txtNumber.setText("" + number);
            currentValue = "" + number;     
        }       
    }

    private void initGUI() {

        btnDecrement = new JButton("-");
        btnDecrement.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        btnDecrement.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                decrement();
            }
        });
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        add(btnDecrement, BorderLayout.WEST);

        txtNumber = new JTextField();
        txtNumber.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        txtNumber.setText("0");
        txtNumber.setEditable(false);
        add(txtNumber, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        txtNumber.setColumns(2);

        btnIncrement = new JButton("+");
        btnIncrement.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        btnIncrement.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                increment();
            }
        });
        add(btnIncrement, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are those JButtons or are you drawing the lines and text manually?

Comment: *"how do i add an ActionListener to it,"*  To what?  The `-`/`+` symbols, the `12` area, or both?  If the `-`/`+` are `JButton` & the `12` a `JTextArea` the answer is simpler.   What are they?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  As an aside.  I'd tend to use a `JSpinner` with a [`SpinnerNumberModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html) for this.

Comment: Yes, tell us how you implement that custom component.

Comment: Are you aware of `JSpinner` component, are you sure you want to implement same functionality yourself?

Comment: Looking at your code you already attached `ActionListener`s to the buttons. That should just work, so what exactly is the problem ?

Comment: `ZoomSelector`  ***Deifinitely*** a `JSpinner` that can be cycled up/down using the arrow keys (is what I as a user would want for that control - that or a `JSlider`).  Please explain what this component is supposed to do that is better than the already working alternatives.

Comment: `setSize(new Dimension(125, 26));`  That should be `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 26));` and returned as the overridden `getPreferredSize()` (and it should be based on the preferred size of the children rather than 'magic numbers').

Comment: Instead of something like `gui.add(new ZoomSelector());` try `SpinnerNumberModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(12,0,20,1);
                JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model);
                gui.add(spinner);`.  Trust me on this.

Comment: Alright guys, I'll use a JSpinner instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use JSpinner.
It is an easy way to move a value up or down.
EXAMPLE BY Java tutorials:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorialJWS/uiswing/components/ex6/SliderDemo.jnlp

Comment: Is there an example you could include in this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I added an action listener to a custom Swing component here: [JCropFrame](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=76)

You have to create your own `EventListener` and extend `AWTEvent` and  `AWTEventMulticaster`